# Shared element transitions not working with picasso

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I am trying to apply a shared elements transition from an element from a `recyclerView` to an activity.
The images of `imageView`s of the recycler view is loaded from URLs using picasso.
But when I click on an image, (where its supposed to show the next activity with my image) the image doesn't show at all.

**View Holder:**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
        ActivityCompat.postponeEnterTransition((Activity)holder.myImage.getContext());
        holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
        holder.genre.setText(movie.getGenre());
        holder.year.setText(movie.getYear());


        holder.myImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity)view.getContext(), holder.myImage, "imageAnimation");

                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), details.class);
                view.getContext().startActivity(i, options.toBundle());



            }
        });



        //load image from the web
        Picasso.with(holder.myImage.getContext()).load(movie.getImageURL()).placeholder(R.drawable.album1).into(holder.myImage, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
               ActivityCompat.startPostponedEnterTransition((Activity)holder.myImage.getContext());

            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                ActivityCompat.startPostponedEnterTransition((Activity)holder.myImage.getContext());
            }
        });


    }
```

OnCreate:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        supportPostponeEnterTransition();


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        .
        .
```

I want to show the image loaded from the URL in the next activity.

[image: Video:]

**EDIT:** The animation worked with a single static image before. The issue appeared after adding Picasso.

Answer (score 0):

> The image is not showing because there has to be the same image or any other view ( **with same transition name in the 2nd activity**  )  i.e "imageAnimation"

Just add the view to the other activity(a bigger version would be better)  and give it the same transition name ..it will work..

Comment: I have already added android:transitionName="imageAnimation" to both of my ImageViews.

Comment: each imageview should have unique transition name in recyclerview